# there is no default value + symfony2 + crud

Tags: symfony

sf 2.8.4 with sylius 0.17

i had generated a controller and routes with generate:doctrine:crud

i can list all datas, but on show and edit, always got this error:

```
Controller "St\AppBundle\Controller\TranslationDomainController::showAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$translationdomain" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).
```

here the show action

```
    public function showAction(TranslationDomain $translationdomain)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($translationdomain->getId(), 'administration_translations_domain_delete');

    return $this->render('StAppBundle:TranslationDomain:show.html.twig', array(
        'translationdomain' => $translationdomain,
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),        ));
}
```

and the route

```
administration_translations_domain_show:
pattern:  /{id}/show
defaults: { _controller: "StAppBundle:TranslationDomain:show", id : 1 }
requirements:
    id : \d+
    _method : get
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are using a param converter

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html

You have to disable the auto-conversion of type-hinted method arguments feature by setting the auto_convert flag to false.

#### Look at:

```
# app/config/config.yml

sensio_framework_extra:
    request:
        converters: true
        auto_convert: false
```

#### Change to:

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    request:
        converters: true
        auto_convert: true
```

At the end you should always request for an object identifier. It's safe and semantic correct. You want to 'show/edit/update/delete' concrete entity.

If you really wants to have a default show for your set of entities create route like a '/show/default' and use this route with 'show/choose default' link.